# Remove Notications for User while subscribed to app

Tags: swift

I am trying to make it so a notification asking the user to subscribe will not appear anymore when the user is subscribed to my app, below i s my notifi[image]cations class i am implementing, just having a hard time figuring out how to add code in to null out the alert when they are actually subscribed.

```
import Foundation
    import UserNotifications
    
    class Notifications: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        
        func notificationRequest() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                if success {
                    print("All set!")
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        func addNotification() {
            print("foi")
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "WARNING: Safari at risk! ⚠️"
            content.subtitle = "Tap here to secure your device!"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
            // show this notification 3 days from now 259200
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 259200, repeats: true)
    
            // choose a random identifier
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
            // add our notification request
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        }
        
        func clearNotification() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the user is subscribed? If you answer this question don't you also have the answer to your own question?

Comment: yeah i was just overcomplicating it in my head, i just wrapped those functions in an if statement that checked if they were subscribed, sometimes i cant get my head out of the weeds to see the simple answer